# UK visa travel history

Tags: visas, uk

From my country, you can enter two neighbor counties with the national identity card. I have entered those countries several times over the past 10 years since my family lives there. Sometimes I cross with passport and sometimes with id card so I do not have the matching stamps for some of the stamps in my passport and cannot enter them. I entered some of the trips to those two countries that I have both stamps in my passport. I entered this information in a free form field with additional data at the end of the application but not sure if it is enough.

Can anyone suggest what should I do?

Comment: To be clear, the form is not asking what stamps you have in your passport, it's asking where you've visited. Not all visits to countries result in stamps, this is very normal and will not be surprising to the entry clearance officer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You tell them that, I seriously doubt it if anyone would be interested in it, but if it is you would tell them exactly that. Very unlikely it would raise any eyebrows.